# Reading Data From Database and storing in Array List, but the array list is showing null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlets, dao

I'm trying to retrieve data from db and displaying it in a table form using JSP.

The problem is when I do `query.list()` it is returning null.

There are 10 records in the db.

How do I retrieve all the records ?

Below is my DTO

```
public class TaskDAO {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Task> getUserTasks(String userName) {
        // Task task = getTasksByUserName(userName);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Task> task = new LinkedList<Task>();
        try {
             transaction = session.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            Query query = session.createQuery("select id, taskDescription from Task where USERNAME='"
                    + userName + "'");
            task = query.list();
            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return task;

    }

}
```

Below is my JSP

```
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="com.sk.app.dto.Task"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.sk.app.controller.Success"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Tasks</h2>
<table>
<%
List tasks =  (List)request.getAttribute("taskList");
Iterator iterator = tasks.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Task currentTask = (Task) iterator.next();%>

    <tr>
        <td> <%=currentTask.getId()%></td>
        <td> <%=currentTask.getTaskDescription()%></td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
```

Below is my Servlet

```
public class Success extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        try {
            TaskDAO taskDAO = new TaskDAO();

            List<Task> taskList = taskDAO.getUserTasks(userName);

            request.setAttribute("taskList", taskList);
            Iterator<Task> iterator = taskList.iterator();
            int count = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                count ++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("task.jsp");

            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Below is my Task dto

```
public class Task {
    private int id;
    private String taskDescription;
    private String USERNAME;
    public String getUserName() {
        return USERNAME;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.USERNAME = userName;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTaskDescription() {
        return taskDescription;
    }
    public void setTaskDescription(String taskDescription) {
        this.taskDescription = taskDescription;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task [id=" + id + ", taskDescription=" + taskDescription
                + ", USERNAME=" + USERNAME + "]";
    }


}
```

When I debugged the program this is the result I get on inspecting `task = query.list();` [image: debug]

The below image is the table structure, the username column is foreign key to user table.  [image: table]

Comment: This is a giant collection of "don't do that"s. Don't use scriptlets, don't use string pasting to generate queries, don't hand-write transaction management or DAOs, and don't write servlets by hand. I can replace your entire code with about 10 lines in Spring and 10 lines of HTML template.

Comment: @chrylis I'm new to this, learning from scratch. Trying to implement what I learnt.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, that you don't get any data from the database, because of your `HQL` is incorrect. You need to get all `Task`

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Task where USERNAME='"
                    + userName + "'");
```

Check your property `USERNAME`. It has to be a persistent class property, not a database column!

Just use `transaction = session.beginTransaction();` in place of

```
transaction = session.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
```

use `List<Task> task = null;` in place of

```
List<Task> task = new LinkedList<Task>();
```

Comment: Still the same, returns null.

Comment: @ShashiKiran Do this `System.out.println(session.createQuery("from Task where username='3'").list());`

Comment: This is output I got for that ' [com.sk.app.dto.Task@7a87274f, com.sk.app.dto.Task@3f25f261, com.sk.app.dto.Task@544bdeaa, com.sk.app.dto.Task@41079622, com.sk.app.dto.Task@5911b388] '


This not correct right ?

Comment: I Created toString method, and this is the output after that - '[Task [id=1, taskDescription=null, USERNAME=null], Task [id=3, taskDescription=null, USERNAME=null], Task [id=7, taskDescription=null, USERNAME=null], Task [id=9, taskDescription=null, USERNAME=null], Task [id=10, taskDescription=null, USERNAME=null]]'

Comment: @ShashiKiran Looks like, you get data from the database. Please, add `Task` to your question.

Comment: Added the task class.

Comment: @ShashiKiran Where your mapping?

Comment: I had mapped in a mapping file, the mistake I did was had not mapped the USERNAME so was not getting the list.

Anyways thanks for your help, will give you a thumbs up for that

Comment: There is still a problem in this as I have to hard code the where clause, when I pass userName in the query not getting the table.

Comment: Can't got you. Please, add an example to your question.